# Symfony 3: How to submit forms in the collection of forms separately?

Tags: symfony

I'm wondering if I could submit forms inside a collection separately? I have very long form collection with buttons to save each subform (Basically filling and validating the form at once would be difficult). So clicking the button suppose to only submit corresponding subform, but it submits whole collection.

```
getDoctrine()->getManager();

$user = $this->getUser();

if(!count($user->getApplicants())) {
$app = new Applicant();
$app->setUser($user);
$user->setApplicants($app);
}

if(!count($user->getAddresses())) {
$address = new Address();
$address->setUser($user);
$user->setAddresses($address);
}

if(!count($user->getCompanies())) {
$company = new Company();
$company->setUser($user);
$user->setCompanies($company);
}

if(!count($user->getDirectors())) {
$director = new Director();
$director->setUser($user);
$user->setDirectors($director);
}

$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'submitApplicants' === $form- 
>getClickedButton()->getName()) {

$applicant = $form->getData()->getApplicants()[0];

$applicant->setUser($user);

$em->persist($applicant);

$em->flush();

return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
'form' => $form->createView()
]);

}
if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'submitAddresses' === $form- 
>getClickedButton()->getName()) {

$address = $form->getData()->getAddresses()[0];

$em->persist($address);

$em->flush($address);

return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
'form' => $form->createView()
]);

}

if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'submitCompanies' === $form- 
>getClickedButton()->getName()) {

$company = $form->getData()->getCompanies()[0];

$em->persist($company);
$em->flush($company);

return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
'form' => $form->createView()
]);

}

if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'submitDirectors' === $form- 
>getClickedButton()->getName()) {

$director = $form->getData()->getDirectors()[0];

$em->persist($director);

$em->flush($director);

return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
'form' => $form->createView()
]);

}

//$em->flush();
}

return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
'form' => $form->createView()
]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you need to submit the subform via Javascript. Add some js code to the submit button to:

1. Perform an ajax POST request to a controller action
2. Make some checks to the form data
3. Return back either an error message or some HTML (whatever you want)
4. Do something with that message

That way you will be able to submit each form separately.
Also change the type of the submit button to plain button. Otherwise you will trigger a form submit for the whole page.